# How can I select and block row for each thread in oracle?(There is a working example for PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle, select

I have table `products`:

```
id  name count description          status  expiration_date
1   Hz    1    Test1537208034036    NEW     2018-09-17
2   Pz    3    Test1537209516789    NEW     2018-10-17
3   Uz    7    Test1537210999618    NEW     2018-08-17
4   Mz    12   Test1537212483215    NEW     2018-11-17
```

I need select row with the biggest ***count*** and status = ***NEW***. For this I can write on postgreSQL:

```
Select * 
from products 
where status = 'NEW' 
order by count desc 
LIMIT 1
```

But if 4 threads will start doing this select - each thread get equal row(with count = 12). I can rewrite this query and it work fine:

```
Select * 
from products 
where status = 'NEW' 
order by count desc 
LIMIT 1 
for update of products skip locked
```

But I can not repeat this in **Oracle**.

```
SELECT p.* 
from (
  Select * 
  from products 
  where status = 'NEW' 
  order by count desc
) p 
WHERE p.ROWNUM = 1 
FOR UPDATE OF products SKIP LOCKED
```

Oracle has not `LIMIT 1` and `rownum` works differently. I need get first row from *ordered* table(`order by desc`) `but this row not locked`.

How can I repeat logic like PostgreSQL. Maybe my select is wrong.

If you look easier, that's what I want to get - I have table and many threads. I need each thread to receive the oldest row from the database (or the largest count) and only it is one. other threads should not receive it. The next thread should receive the oldest (or largest) row following it.

Comment: Oracle has `fetch first x rows only` instead of `limit`(actually Postgres also supports that syntax). But you would need to fetch rownum _inside_ of the sub-select with an alias and use that on the _outside_ . You current code uses `rownum` from the _outer_ query, not the inner query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name An example for Oracle not exact. Just the problem is that oracle use 2 select and not lock row. If more precisely, then 4 threads block the same row

Comment: if I would fetch rownum inside of the sub-select with an alias and use that on the outside - all threads immediately perform the first select without blocking. and if, on the contrary, I will order by for single row because the internal select will give me one row. and I have to sort all the rows and select one and then block it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use dynamic sql. The lock is acquired at a fetch time. You fetch one record and it is get locked at the same time. Keep in mind that record is unlocked once you finish the transaction - commit or rollback.

Here is the short example of function which returns the next `products.id` for your thread.

```
create or replace function get_next_unlocked_id
return number
is
  cRefCursor sys_refcursor;
  rRecord    products%rowtype;
begin
  -- open cursor. No locks so far
  open cRefCursor for 
    'select * from products '||
    'where status = ''NEW'' '||
    'order by count desc '||
    'for update skip locked';

  -- we fetch and lock at the same time one record
  fetch cRefCursor into rRecord;

  -- close cursor
  close cRefCursor;

  -- return ID or any other attribute(s)
  return rRecord.id; 

end;
```

Comment: all 4 threads  make `open cursor. No locks so far` and when each thread will `fetch cRefCursor into rRecord;` each thread will lock same row because all 4 threads get same result in first select

Comment: for example I have 5 threads and 5 rows in table. All threads simultaneously request data - each thread make select and get all 5 rows(ordered) and only after that first row blocks. But second thread try block first row from same data...

Comment: They don't get the same data, they get different data. This is the feature of "for update skip locked" -  just test it. And don't forget to set the autocommit to false since record is unlocked at a commit time.

Comment: [72000][14551] ORA-14551: Unable to perform DML operation inside the request. ORA-06512: in "IP696.GET_NEXT_UNLOCKED_ID", line 8

Comment: if I remove this part `for update skip locked` function works

Comment: You can't run it in an SQL query, the following generates an error ORA-14551 - 'select get_next_unlocked_id from dual'. You need to make it as a function call.

Comment: `select get_next_unlocked_id() from DUAL;` I do so

Comment: You can't use this type of function in 'select from dual' statement.You should create a pl/sql function call, something like this: begin dbms_output.put_line(get_next_unlocked_id); end;

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL?