# Call oracle function in Spring JPA

Tags: java, oracle, function, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I have this

```
DECLARE
  c number;
BEGIN
  c := get_next_unlocked_id();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('id: ' || c);
END;
```

This query print function result. But I need return this result in my Spring data JPA repositoru or entitiManager.

I try this:

```
@Override
    public Long getOld() {
        Long id = (Long) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT get_next_unlocked_id() FROM DUAL").getSingleResult();
        return id;
    }
```

but I get error:

```
2019-01-10 15: 28: 25.768 ERROR 6724 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ORA-14551: the DML operation cannot be performed inside the request
ORA-06512: on "MY.GET_NEXT_UNLOCKED_ID", line 8
```

Answer (score 1):

**The function you are calling in a select (`get_next_unlocked_id`) attempts to do data modification**, which is not allowed the way you tried it.

The problem is that your solution appears to be "querying" while in effect it is modifying data. I assume your function increments some counter or updates something? The ORA errorcode you received is quite descriptive, here is the [longer explanation](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_14551_cannot_perform_a_dml_operation_inside_a_query.htm).

**The solution either way is to use [CallableStatements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550539/821786) from Java.**

Comment: I'm trying to get a locked row for each thread. This function was suggested to me by SO. Here is a related question, maybe you can also help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54125380/4781349

Comment: I am sorry but I would not get involved in that question. This here was straightforward question, but in the other you are asking for help in a solution which I think is not a good direction at all. I do not know how do that because I would not (and have not done) that before. You will need somebody else for that. In your place I would decide where would I place the complexity: app or DB, and keep it there. Mixing it that much is going to bring lots of troubles.